# DFA -> RE using State Elimination

Tags: regex, dfa

Would anyone be able to explain to me how I would go about converting this DFA to a Regular Expression using the "State Elimination" Method. I have looked online but don't quite understand the few examples I've seen.

[image]

Thank you.

Comment: This question is off topic for SO since it's more about CS theory than actual programming. The right site for these kinds of questions is cs.stackexchange.com. However, even getting on the right stackexchange site, I'd recommend telling us a little better what it is you don't understand. Just asking for another explanation will likely not get you what you want.

Comment: @GGordonWorleyIII. Definitely not off-topic. These types of questions come up all the time in real world programing. But if you're just a script monkey plugging code fragments into a framework, then you wouldn't know that. Sorry for the snarkiness, but someone has to stand up for real software design.

Answer (score 8):

[image]

First Convert the edges to RE's

[image]

Eliminate state 1

[image]

Note edge from 3 --> 3

[image]

Result = `(0+10)*11(0+1)*`